# Calculating payment arrears from a table where payments and bills are in the same fields. Has to be in t-sql / sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table structure like below:

```
Account Number | Transaction Type   | Transaction Date   | Bill Due Date  | Transaction Number | Transaction Amount
---------------|--------------------|--------------------|----------------|--------------------|-------------------
1              | B                  |  7/03/2019         | 7/04/2019      | 1                  | $82.68 
1              | P                  |  12/03/2019        | 30/12/3999     | 2                  | $819.31 
1              | B                  |  22/02/2019        | 25/03/2019     | 3                  | $919.46 
2              | B                  |  3/04/2019         | 4/05/2019      | 1                  | $134.21 
2              | P                  |  8/04/2019         | 30/12/3999     | 2                  | $361.10 
2              | P                  |  13/04/2019        | 30/12/3999     | 3                  | $885.79 
3              | B                  |  6/03/2019         | 6/04/2019      | 1                  | $228.73 
3              | P                  |  11/03/2019        | 30/12/3999     | 2                  | $939.31 
3              | B                  |  31/03/2019        | 1/05/2019      | 3                  | $630.37 
4              | B                  |  20/04/2019        | 21/05/2019     | 1                  | $915.31 
4              | P                  |  25/04/2019        | 30/12/3999     | 2                  | $538.94 
4              | B                  |  2/04/2019         | 3/05/2019      | 3                  | $85.28
```

I need to calculate the arrears for each account and then aged it, I.e. calculate how old that arrears is. I then bucket it by age (0-30,31-60,60-90,90+). If a payment is made, it is a first in first out process (oldest arrears gets paid off first). When a payment is made, the bill due date is 3999-12-31

I have built this using SAS as I have developed a credit score car but now I need to implement this in SQL Server 2017. I would use Retain Etc from SAS but I am yet find a fucntion in t-sql that can do this.

Is it even possible?

I have used rolling sums (-bill (B), +Pay(P)) but I am struggling with the aging of the arrears and bucketing them.

I also have to look at it over snapshots and then calculate my modelling variables on these ( i use the analytical window functions for this).

I have also tried window functions with aging but I just cant replicate the outputs from the SAS script I developed.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Table is indexed on account number and trans is. Has approx 2 mill unique account numbers and 500m transactions

Output will look like the following:

[image]

Comment: Why use `39991230` and not `NULL`?

Comment: Its the way in which our source table is derived. When I deal with it I convert them to Nulls

Comment: What are you expecting as output from your sample data?

Comment: Basically a table that has account number and end of month arrears buckets and information. The sas table I generate is a month end snapshot so calculate the diff between the due date and previous/current month end. Ideally it would have month 1,2,3 etc longitudinally and then the columns would be the arrears information for that end of month row.

Comment: I don't mean an explanation. I mean what is the actual data you expect as output from the sample? Something so we know if what we are doing is correct.

Comment: Could you give us what the output for account #1 would be. It would seem that your trans dates do not tall with the trans id. I would expect a subsequent transaction to have a date greater than the previous one. 

How can Account #1 Transacrion #3 be before the other transactions?

Comment: using the transaction date as the point in which to calculate the arrears the output looks like the above- I have added it to the question as its too long for the comments.